# Encountering unreal operation while finding limit

Tags: limits

The question is:

find the limit as x approaches infinity of f(x), where $f(x) = (x)^{1/2}(x-3)^{-1/2}$

My approach, starting by modifying f(x):

$f(x)=[{(x-3)^{1/2}x^{-1/2}}]^{-1}$

=$[(x-3)x^{-1})]^{\frac{-1}{2}}$

=$[(0-3x)^{-1}]^{-1/2}$

=$(-3x)^{\frac 1 2}$
no real answer for positive real values of x

Comment: Sorry for miserable format, taking a look right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that $x\cdot x^{-1}$ is **one**, not **zero** (see your second-to-last line).

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\sqrt{\dfrac x{x-3}}=\sqrt{\dfrac1{\lim_{x\to\infty}(1-3/x)}}$$

$$=\sqrt{\dfrac1{(1-0)}}$$

Comment: Could you please explain how you shifted the limit notation from outside of the whole function into the denominator while the numerator changed from x to 1?